# Flask app deployment with dokku

Tags: flask, gunicorn, dokku

I`m trying to deploy helloworld Flask app with Dokku following the manual.

Requirements:

```
Flask==0.9
Jinja2==2.6
Werkzeug==0.8.3
gunicorn==0.17.2
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn wsgi:app -b 127.0.0.1:$PORT
```

wsgi.py:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

docker container listens to port 49153

wget 127.0.0.1:49153 gives me

```
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:49153... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.
```

docker logs gives no errors:

```
2014-02-01 08:35:03 [10] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.17.2
2014-02-01 08:35:03 [10] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:5000 (10)
2014-02-01 08:35:03 [10] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2014-02-01 08:35:03 [15] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15
```

How can I debug this error?

Answer (score 0):

try update dokku to stable, or setup dokku on clean ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your Procfile. You should not specify Flask to listen on 127.0.0.1 only. Try 0.0.0.0 instead.

Thus, I suggest you can modify your Procfile to be like this:

```
web: gunicorn wsgi:app -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

Answer (score 0):

don't specify host and port in your Procfile, 
`web: gunicorn wsgi:app` is enough